# Problem with URL retrieved from branch.io deep-link

Tags: angular, branch.io

i've created a branch.io deep-link domain with *".link"* on the end, i configured it and it works well with the redirection to Android and iOS apps.
I also have an Angular webapp, where i installed the branch.io sdk and setted up the init function in AppComponent:

```
Branch.init('my_live_key', {}, function(err, data) {
   console.log(err, data);
});
```

The problem is that when i navigate to *"app.link/route"* i only get redirect to "app.com" and receiving no information about the full url path.
This is the object i get from the console.log:

```
{
    "data": "{\"+clicked_branch_link\":false,\"+is_first_session\":true}",
    "data_parsed": {
        "+clicked_branch_link": false,
        "+is_first_session": true
    },
    "has_app": false,
    "identity": null,
    "developer_identity": null,
    "referring_identity": null,
    "referring_link": null
}
```

I tried to log the errors and use the cdn of the library but nothing happens.
What i expect is a detailed object with the full path from my .link domain.